# Symfony 4: How to disable profiler in test-env through command line

Tags: symfony, environment-variables, symfony4, profiler

I am trying for quite some time now to disable the profiler in the test-environment. The only way it works is manually setting `APP_ENV=test` in file `.env` but I want to do this through the command line, not by editing a file.

Here's everything I tried:

- I tried editing `bin/console` like described in Chris Brown's answer in this thread: [Load different .env file with a Symfony 4 command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49345965/load-different-env-file-with-a-symfony-4-command) (I also added the file `.env.test`, and according to xdebug it loads the appropriate file and runs through the appropriate code and also the variables `$env` and `$debug` get the appropriate value when I run the server with `--env=test --no-debug`)
- I tried setting `profiler: enabled: false` like described in flu's answer in this thread: [How to disable profiler in Symfony2 in production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13901972/how-to-disable-profiler-in-symfony2-in-production) (in config/packages/test/framework.yaml)
- I tried setting the profiler line in bundles.php to

`Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle::class => ['dev' => true],`

and to

`Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => false, 'test_cached' => false],`

I tried those solutions separately and also all together, still the profiler keeps popping up. Does anybody have an idea?

**EDIT:**
After applying Alister Bulman's answer the command gives me this:

```
#php bin/console -e test debug:config framework profiler

Current configuration for "framework.profiler"
==============================================

enabled: true
collect: false
only_exceptions: false
only_master_requests: false
dsn: 'file:%kernel.cache_dir%/profiler'
```

**EDIT 2:**
Thanks to Jared Farrish I just found out the browser is receiving the website in "dev" mode although the server is started in test environment on cli. Obviously editing `bin/console` and `public/index.php` is not enough, they're not called when the server receives a request from the browser.

**EDIT 3:**
So I found out the http request goes first to `public/index.php`, but whatever I do, I cannot seem to make anything available there which was defined in `bin/console` although the whole server is started there in the first place. Anyone an idea how this can be done?

Comment: Have you run it as `bin/console ... --env=test`? This is how it's supposed to work.

Comment: Yes. I figured this is how it's supposed to work indeed, but the profiler just pops up nevertheless.

Comment: These refer to the Web Profiler, which should only run from http. Is it coming up somehow when you run your cli tests?

Comment: uhm... good question. I guess I don't have those right now, I am a Symfony beginner in my first project. My question was about the web profiler indeed. Any quick way of testing what you mean though?

Comment: I was confused by this too when I started Symfony; the `test` environment is a configuration for running unit tests and other (generally command line) operations. If you're trying to disable the profiler in web requests. look at the code in `web/app.php`. `bin/console` is analogous to `web/app.php` for the command line, so they both configure different front controllers.

Comment: I don't have any file `web/app.php`, I can find in my IDE (PHPStorm) `vendor/symfony/console/Application.php` and `vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Application.php`. Oh so the "test" environment is only for unit-tests?

Comment: Whatever the frontend's front controller is; if you're seeing the web profiler in a browser, it's the first file that your server hands the request to. I'm on 3.4 and it was `web/app.php` and `web/app_dev.php`, generally, although that might be different under 4.

Comment: And yes, `test` here refers to unit or other test rigs. You can create your own environments, like `dev-no-profile` that disables profiling but keeps debug logging or something. Generally, though, there's something odd about what's being described.

Comment: yes, the first file the request goes to is `bin/console`. I stepped through that, even to all other called nested functions and I see nothing out of the ordinary, all commands, ect are executed correctly and also .env.test is read instead of .env when I execute the server with `--env=test --no-debug`. Nevertheless the web profiler is shown when I visit a site from the app. I find this very strange.

Comment: It sounds like you're telling the cli call to be test, but your app's web front controller has dev setup and it enables the profiler. If that last sentence refers to visiting the site in a browser. Changing the test environment setting and calling it from the command line won't affect the environment the web process uses.

Comment: Yes, I have the same feeling. But how is that possible? The server is started on cli, why would the browser receive a different environment?

Comment: They use different controllers (`bin/console` and `web/app.php` or whatever), which configure things differently. Also, generally a server like Apache is calling the server's web front controller; running the local PHP server is going to access the same front controller. The fact they're both within the proximity of a cli doesn't mean they share bootstraps.

Comment: Okay... so I have to find the other "entry point". I did the same to `public/index.php` as it had more or less the same code as `bin/console`, but still the same result. Good point though. It's pretty obvious what I see in the browser isn't the test environment.

EDIT: And now I have confirmation of that fact, the profiler shows me following information:

Profiler token 237de7
Environment dev
Debug disabled

Comment: Yeah, you have session, user, router, etc., that you generally don't have on the cli. It's a different environment than commands on a cli.

Comment: So I found out where the request goes. Opposite to what I thought it **does** go to `public/index.php`. But there is not any relationship with the commands I provided by starting the server with `bin/console server:start`. The env stays dev, and I cannot change it (by command line). Even creating a global variable in `bin/console` does not make it's value available in `public/index.php`. But the whole server is started by `bin/console server:start` in the first place and in it, all values are corresponding to the parameters I started the server with in the first place. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it myself. What I did was use a functionality of php.ini which is called "auto_prepend_file" where you can specify a PHP file which gets executed automatically before the actual PHP content is executed. So in there I put a path to a file with following content:

```
<?php

$_ENV['APP_ENV'] = 'test';
$_ENV['APP_DEBUG'] = 0;
```

Answer (score 4):

The profile can be enabled, or disabled in the framework configuration.

```
> bin/console -e dev debug:config framework profiler

Current configuration for "framework.profiler"
==============================================
only_exceptions: false
enabled: true
collect: true
only_master_requests: false
dsn: 'file:%kernel.cache_dir%/profiler'
```

In a newly generated project, these are best set (for the test environment) in the `config/packages/test/framework.yaml` file.

```
framework:
    profiler: 
        enabled: false
        collect: false
        # optionally others
```

Documentation for the framework config (profiler, and the rest) is at https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#profiler

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately though this did not solve my problem, the profiler still pops up. 

EDIT: That's weird, the command gives me 

php bin/console -e test debug:config framework profiler

Current configuration for "framework.profiler"
==============================================

enabled: true
collect: false
only_exceptions: false
only_master_requests: false
dsn: 'file:%kernel.cache_dir%/profiler'

although I also specifically have enabled set to false.